One of the benchtop power supplies not powering battery based LCD clock
I have a store-bought LCD wall clock that works off 1.5V AA. I tried powering it via Kikusui PAR160A benchtop power supply and it did not work. When I tried Kepco MPS 620M, it worked.
What could be the issue?
thanks

We cannot know that. Or rather, there are so many things it could be so it is best that you try to give out more info. Like how you connected them, and how you operated them. Or did you enable the output.

thanks for your response. i removed the battery. connected benchtop's positive to a positive terminal on the clock board and negative to negative. Kikusui has adjustable current protection, but Kepco does not.

Can you power other things with the supply or is this the first time you use the supply? Do you know if it works, or have you just not pushed the output enable button?

yes, the power supply works. i've been using it for years. i did push output button.

Did you measure anything about the situation? Voltages, currents, ripple, or did anything indicate broken wires or bad connections, etc?

hmm. connections look ok. no noise on oscope. The only difference from the good supply is that when the bad one is off, it sits at -200mV. when i connected oscope ,the very 1st time i did see LCD come up - with some segments missing, but it was up. now it is always not powered. I'll try to leave it on for a while see if it ever comes up.

My gut feeling is that the clock's extremely low current draw is not playing well with the power supply's regulation.

thanks @vir . the working PS does have better regulation and ripple parameters. i did not realize that would make such difference. Good PS: Ripple and noise 0.1mV rms and 1mv p-p. the "bad" PS: load regulation 3mV.

does it mean my DC-DC down converter to 1.5V should be that good? I am trying to replace 1.5V AA with wall power.

When i use the "bad" PS to feed 1.5V LDO, the output is good and the clock turns on. So, just something keep in mind about that PS.
